# Instant Server-Client Communication, C#?

Tags: c#, php, wpf, wcf, client-server

I have been doing research for a few months now on the possibility of client-server communication. I have experimented with many methods such as WebORB and FluorineFX, which are both servers designed to deal with client/server authentication.

WebORB only runs on Windows for their .NET version as far as I can tell, and I would much rather use an open source system. I have tried using FluorineFX, but I think their must be a simpler way for me to build my own simple system from the ground up.

I have been using Dropbox for a while now, and I like the way that the client-server communication is instant. As far as I can tell (from some Google searches) the client doesn't open a port of its own, and just communicates with the Dropbox server through port 80. An example of its instant communication is where you may delete a file on Dropbox on their website, and instantly the server communicates with the client telling it what has happened. I don't know how this instant communication is possible without opening a port.

I can create a system that uses fetching from the client, asking the server every 10 seconds or so to see if there are any updates, but I would like a method to be able to ***push the information from the server to the client.***

***My server runs Linux*** so I don't think I can use WCF, and ideally I am looking for a way to make PHP and C# communicate with each other.

I would love to hear any advice that anyone has and how they deal with the problem.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the good old .NET Remoting which runs perfectly with Mono?

You can choose between a TcpChannel (for performance) and a HttpChannel (to pass proxy/firewall easily).

For push notifications, you can open a connection to your server and wait for an answer indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have decided to go with Mono and HttpChannel because of it's simplicity. It's much simpler for me to use than WCF!

Answer (score 2):

You CAN use WCF to communicate with any platform. Just make sure you're using an endpoint which your target machine support: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733107.aspx